# view and show the result of windows.partition function in pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In code segment, I saw it uses windows function as follows.

```
test_by_time = Window.partitionBy("testId").orderBy("Time")
```

My question is that how to view the results of the `windows.partitonby`, i.e., `test_by_time` here. I tried to use `test_by_time.show()`, but the error AttributeError: 'WindowSpec' object has no attribute` 'show' is given.

Comment: `window.partitionBy` isn't returning a data frame. It is a windowing spec that you use with a data frame.

Comment: @Andrew, sometimes, we can see pretty complicated usages of window.PartionBy in practie,  then what are the ways to understand the related logic.